# Ubuntu connect Iphone as drive instead of image viewer

Tags: 16.04

I recently got an iphone and accidentally connected it as image viewer. How do I revert it and connect it as a drive?

Comment: You have to change it in your iphone, since this type of connection is not managed by Computer SO.

Comment: How do I change it in my iPhone?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in iPhone, I just have android.

Comment: I spoke to an iPhone support person. He says there is no specific settings to change in phone